# URL Patterns of custom SpringVaadinServlet

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin (7.6.1) with SpringBoot (1.3.0) and I got a problem regarding the application URL in the browser.

If I call "http://localhost:8080/myApp/" everything works fine -Spring Security blocks the request, redirects to login page, and after an authentication it calls the defaultSuccessUrl ("/#!"). But if the user calls "http://localhost:8080/myApp" (without the last slash) Spring Security also works but redirects to the savedRequestUrl. In this case an error message ("**failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./vaadin/vaadinbootstrap.js**") is displayed.

Generally I want Spring Security to redirect to the savedRequestUrl, so what should I do? Does the URL pattern of the Servlet is beeing my problem? In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092708/4295746) there is an example of an Annotation based WebServlet but if this is my problem how should I integrate it in my application?

I defined my own SpringVaadinServlet which overrides the default vaadinServlet bean. My classes look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "vaadinServlet")
    public CustomSpringVaadinServlet springVaadinServlet()
    {
        return new CustomSpringVaadinServlet();
    }
}

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{ 
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        [...]
        return application.sources(MyApp.class);
    }
}

public class CustomSpringVaadinServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6507628193889155490L;

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringVaadinServletWsi.class);

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException
    {
        super.servletInitialized();

        getService().setSystemMessagesProvider(new SystemMessagesProvider()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5253418651979378723L;

            @Override
            public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo)
            {
                CustomizedSystemMessages messages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
                messages.setCommunicationErrorCaption("Kommunikationsfehler");
                [...]
                return messages;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked with custom SpringVaadinServlets myself, but with the default servlet, in the spring security configuration, allowing `/vaadinServlet**` and `/VAADIN**`did work for me, you could give it a try and see if it solves the problem.